# If statement conditional is getting ignored in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe(df) with 20,000 rows that looks like this:

```
     type letter
1     a     a
2     a     k
3     a     j
4     a     c
5     a     p
...  ...   ...
2523  i     v
2524  i     j
2525  i     k
2526  i     b
...  ...   ...
7900  a     p
7901  a     x
7902  a     c
...  ...   ...
```

I want to create a new column 'match' based on two conditions:
(1) MATCH if type==a and letter==a, b, or c
(2) MATCH if type==i and letter==i, j, or k

So I ran if statements:

```
a.letter=c("a", "b", "c")
i.letter=c("i", "j", "k")

if (df$type=="a") {
  df$match <- ifelse(df$letter %in% a.letter, "MATCH", "NO MATCH")
} else if (df$type=="i") {
   df$match <- ifelse(df$letter %in% i.letter, "MATCH", "NO MATCH")
}
```

My desired output is this:

```
     type letter match
1     a     a    MATCH
2     a     k    NO MATCH
3     a     j    NO MATCH
4     a     c    MATCH
5     a     p    NO MATCH
...  ...   ...   ...
2523  i     v    NO MATCH
2524  i     j    MATCH
2525  i     k    MATCH
2526  i     b    NO MATCH
...  ...   ...   ...
7900  a     p    NO MATCH
7901  a     x    NO MATCH
7902  a     c    MATCH
...  ...   ...
```

However, it seems like the second if statement is getting totally ignored.
My current output looks like this:

```
     type letter match
1     a     a    MATCH
2     a     k    NO MATCH
3     a     j    NO MATCH
4     a     c    MATCH
5     a     p    NO MATCH
...  ...   ...   ...
2523  i     v    NO MATCH
2524  i     j    NO MATCH
2525  i     k    NO MATCH
2526  i     b    NO MATCH
...  ...   ...   ...
7900  a     p    NO MATCH
7901  a     x    NO MATCH
7902  a     c    MATCH
...  ...   ...
```

To troubleshoot, I tried testing with just one if statement and, oddly enough, it would work perfectly fine for the first conditional, but not the second conditional.

This works:

```
if (df$type=="a") {
 df$match <- 0
}
```

But this doesn't (no new column created):

```
if (df$type=="i") {
 df$match <- 0
}
```

Why would R not recognize my second conditional entirely?

Comment: Can you use `dput(df)` to provide a sample of the rows containing "i"? It's possible that there could be a white space character, such as a leading or trailing space, that is causing your second statement to fail to match (for example if the data is actually "i " and not "i".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer if else need to be vectorised as well.

Moreover, you can combine two `ifelse` into one here using `&` and `|`.

```
df <- transform(df, match = ifelse(type == 'a' & letter %in% a.letter | 
                      type == 'i' & letter %in% i.letter, "MATCH", "NO MATCH"))

df

#   type letter    match
#1     a      a    MATCH
#2     a      k NO MATCH
#3     a      j NO MATCH
#4     a      c    MATCH
#5     a      p NO MATCH
#6     i      v NO MATCH
#7     i      j    MATCH
#8     i      k    MATCH
#9     i      b NO MATCH
#10    a      p NO MATCH
#11    a      x NO MATCH
#12    a      c    MATCH
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) -

```
df <- structure(list(type = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "i", "i", "i", 
"i", "a", "a", "a"), letter = c("a", "k", "j", "c", "p", "v", 
"j", "k", "b", "p", "x", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 1):

it's better to use `ifelse` statement while working a vectorized dimension.

```
df <- read.table(textConnection('type letter
1     a     a
2     a     k
3     a     j
4     a     c
5     a     p
2523  i     v
2524  i     j
2525  i     k
2526  i     b
7900  a     p
7901  a     x
7902  a     c'))

a.letter=c("a", "b", "c")
i.letter=c("i", "j", "k")
        
df$match <- ifelse((df$type=='a' & (df$letter %in% a.letter)) | (df$type=='i' & (df$letter %in% i.letter)),'MATCH','NOT MATCH')

df
```

**output ;**

```
   type  letter match    
   <fct> <fct>  <chr>    
 1 a     a      MATCH    
 2 a     k      NOT MATCH
 3 a     j      NOT MATCH
 4 a     c      MATCH    
 5 a     p      NOT MATCH
 6 i     v      NOT MATCH
 7 i     j      MATCH    
 8 i     k      MATCH    
 9 i     b      NOT MATCH
10 a     p      NOT MATCH
11 a     x      NOT MATCH
12 a     c      MATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, this can also be solved using an *update join with a lookup table*.

If the lookup table `lut` is a dataframe which contains all combinations of `type` and `letter` which are considered to be a match, e.g.,

> ```
>   letter type
> 1      a    a
> 2      b    a
> 3      c    a
> 4      i    i
> 5      j    i
> 6      k    i
> ```

then the code below modfies `df` *in place*, i.e., without copying the whole data object so that it gains the additional column `match` as requested:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, match := "NO MATCH"][
  setDT(lut), on = .(type, letter), match := "MATCH"][]
```

> ```
>       rn type letter    match
>  1:    1    a      a    MATCH
>  2:    2    a      k NO MATCH
>  3:    3    a      j NO MATCH
>  4:    4    a      c    MATCH
>  5:    5    a      p NO MATCH
>  6: 2523    i      v NO MATCH
>  7: 2524    i      j    MATCH
>  8: 2525    i      k    MATCH
>  9: 2526    i      b NO MATCH
> 10: 7900    a      p NO MATCH
> 11: 7901    a      x NO MATCH
> 12: 7902    a      c    MATCH
> ```

The look-up table `lut` can be created in different ways. One possibility is to read from text input, e.g.,

```
lut <- readr::read_table("
type letter
a    a
a    b
a    c
i    i
i    j
i    k")
```

Another option is to create it from a *named list*, somehow but not exactly similar to OP's approach, e.g.,

```
lul <- list(a = c("a", "b", "c"),
            i = c("i", "j", "k"))
lut <- setnames(reshape2::melt(lul), c("letter", "type"))
```

#### Data

```
df <- readr::read_table("
rn    type  letter
1     a     a
2     a     k
3     a     j
4     a     c
5     a     p
2523  i     v
2524  i     j
2525  i     k
2526  i     b
7900  a     p
7901  a     x
7902  a     c")
```